# Objective C - Get Rid Of Everything Between <em> and </em>

Tags: objective-c

I have the following string:

```
@"Hello there, this is <em> a string. </em> Here's another scenario with tags, for example, <em> this </em>."
```

I need to ged rid of everything between the `<em>` and `</em>` tags, including the tags, so the result should be this:

```
@"Hello there, this is Here's another scenario with tags, for example, ."
```

How do I get this done with regular expression?

Comment: I have some ideas. But first, is this text dynamic or will it be static?

Comment: Every time I extract articles from fool.com, each article, in its html, always has these tags showing different types of disclaimers that is not relevant to what my user wants to see.

Comment: I know how to do this without regular expression. Let me figure out how to do it how you want it done, should be interesting.

Comment: I think the text will always be dynamic in that I don't know how many "annotated" sections there will be in each article. But I know that I just want to get rid of all these annotations because they contain useless info not related to each article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following method :

```
- (NSString *)stringByStrippingEMTag:(NSString *)str {
    NSRange r;
    NSString *s = [str copy];
    while ((r = [s rangeOfString:@"<em[^>]*>(.*?)</em>" options:NSRegularExpressionSearch]).location != NSNotFound) {
        s = [s stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:r withString:@""];
    } 
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Was going to suggest just stripping the HTML. However I did see the OPs original example of the text he is trying to strip and the HTML will remove some information he needs I think.

Comment: I'm asking for the <em> and </em> tags to be removed ALONG with everything between them.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot. Regular expression syntax is really tough for me to understand :)